# Debug Iron Python from c# using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I am calling iron python from c# by creating Python enginer and executing the script from a file.

```
Dictionary<string, object> options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
options["Debug"] = true;
m_engine = Python.CreateEngine(options);
```

I have set the options Debug to true in the engine.Here the breakpoints are working,but I am unable to see the values of the variables in watch

Can anyone give solution for this?

Comment: Some Visual studio settings need to be changed

Comment: What did you do to get it work? Maybe this is helpful for others too.

Comment: I am able to put breakpoints and that is working, but to see values of the variables, I am just printing the values to the console