# How to debug python part of a project while debugging C# code?

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, debugging

I am working on a software written in C#. The software has a part in which it needs to call a Python script. The Python code contains mathematical expressions written in Sympy. My question is how can I debug the python code using Visual Studio 2015 while debugging the c# code. Due to the fact that it is an existing project, changing the architecture to incorporate Iron Python is not an option (e.g. - [Debug Iron Python from c# using Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300175/debug-iron-python-from-c-sharp-using-visual-studio)). Can anyone provide a solution please. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you just skip the python call like it was another function, and inspect whether the output is correct? If it is maybe you can rule out the python code all together.

Comment: unit test the python code separately as much as possible. Then have a debug flag that will dump detailed traces of the python input and output (perhaps dumping pickled objects) which you can use to update unit tests as needed.

Comment: we have already tried unit testing, however it is not ideal because then we cannot see how it performs with real values, which are impossible to input manually.